# How to find gcd(a,b) % p efficiently where p is a prime?

Tags: java, algorithm, primes, number-theory, greatest-common-divisor

My approach is very simple:

- **First, Finding `gcd(a,b)` using Euclid*'s* Algorithm.**
- **Then taking out mod with `p=10^9+7`**

But I need an efficient way (just need the right track not code):

Values of `a` and `b` could in between `1` to **`10^12`** whereas `p` is a **`prime 10^9+7`**

Comment: what's a problem with your approach?

Comment: How about `tail recursion`? So, you won't be consuming a lot of memory rather than just the current stack frame. Well, since you said `Java`, then you may have to opt for something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be my solution if I had an problem as yours. In my solution, I check the range of `long` whether it may satisfy `10^12`. As you can see the following code, it gives `18`, which means it's ok! Nonetheless, I wouldn't prefer Euclid's GCD because it works lumbering recursively. The fact your range is really big gives rise to consuming a host of memory. So, I'd prefer [Binary GCD Algorithm](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Binary_GCD_algorithm).

```
class Test {
    private static final long P = (long)Math.pow(10, 9) + 7;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Check whether long is suitable in regards to ranges
        System.out.println((int)Math.log10(Long.MAX_VALUE));
        // Your wish up to 10^12, so it's ok!
        int result = calculate(1, (long) Math.pow(10, 12));
        System.out.println(result);

        result = calculate((long) Math.pow(10, 12), (long) Math.pow(10, 12));
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static int calculate(long a, long b) {
        return  (int)(gcd(a, b) % P);
    }

    private static long gcd(long p, long q) {
        // https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/BinaryGCD.java.html
        if (q == 0) return p;
        if (p == 0) return q;

        // p and q even
        if ((p & 1) == 0 && (q & 1) == 0) return gcd(p >> 1, q >> 1) << 1;

            // p is even, q is odd
        else if ((p & 1) == 0) return gcd(p >> 1, q);

            // p is odd, q is even
        else if ((q & 1) == 0) return gcd(p, q >> 1);

            // p and q odd, p >= q
        else if (p >= q) return gcd((p-q) >> 1, q);

            // p and q odd, p < q
        else return gcd(p, (q-p) >> 1);
    }

    private static long EuclidianGCD(long a, long b) { return b==0 ? a : EuclidianGCD(b, a%b); }

}
```

You can check answer of the last one from [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gcd(10%5E12,10%5E12)%20mod%20(7%20%2B%2010%5E9)). Besides, if you insist on usage of Euclid's GCD, try it, it may be stuck! and IMHO it is not efficient whatsoever.

Comment: You can implement the Euclidean algorithm as a loop though, same with binary GCD, so they can both be done without unnecessary stack space usage

Comment: yupp !I have already tried Euclid'd GCD.Its taking too much memory.I will try this one Binary GCD or Stein’s algorithm.thank you!

Comment: @MdUmair Are you solving the August Long on CodeChef? If you used this code as is in your submission then you are going to face a plagiarism penalty.

Comment: @saketk21 will you complain him? Interesting!

Comment: No I am not going to. I'll leave it to chance. I even read a post on Meta to see whether this was allowed. But the accepted answer there says that SO will allow questions to be posted on here as long as they are good. And it is everybody's benefit (even mine) that we learn new things like Binary GCD! I just hope the OP understood the algorithm and implemented it on their own. Check this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179460

Comment: @saketk21 well no offense but I want to ask that why people learning new thing by answers from SO (one of them is mine) don't think to _upvote_ a useful answer. It is no matter indeed but for example you, why didn't you upvote the answer if you've learnt something new? Just asking and wondering otherwise no matter

Comment: @snr Actually I always do! I thought I had on this one too. It just slipped somehow.

Comment: @saketk21 it's excellent habit that I hope everybody can have one day, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177874/discussion-between-saketk21-and-snr).

Comment: @saketk21 Yes you are right.I was solving August Long CodeChef and stuck at this.But I already knew Stein's Algo.My major reason for asking this was not to get points at CodeChef but to learn something new being a beginner.I wanted to know whether I can improvise this gcd % prime by using some MMI or some other technique with the help of prime.